# Как поставить иконку для exe файла на Python чтобы файл можно было открыть на всех пк

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, customtkinter

Пытался поставить иконку для приложения на Python пишу программу на CustomTkinter `app.iconbitmap(r'D:\Explore\logo.ico')`И в **pyinstaller** `pyinstaller --onefile --icon=logo.ico -w main.py` на моем пк оно открываеться без ошибок но если перекинуть программу на другой пк о вылазит ошибка с неудачей в поиске директории `D:\Explore\logo.ico` **как вшить иконку в файл для всех пк??**

Answer (score 0):

Поместите файл иконки в ту же папку, где находится скомпилированный exe-файл.
В коде укажите относительный путь (а не абсолютный как у вас) к иконке:

```
import os
import sys

icon_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'logo.ico')  
app.iconbitmap(icon_path)
```

При компиляции добавить иконку в один файл:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=logo.ico -w main.py
```